# How to encode text to suit languages written from right to lef

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

I am building the site in hebrew..The problem is that every exclamation mark, or any other mark which isnt a letter will pass to the beginning:

Example
"@#$%^&!משפט זה נכתב על ידי"

would be rendered as text when put into a label:
"משפט זה נכתב על ידי@#$%^&!"

How can I prevent that phenomena from happening in TextBoxes, lables..etc.

```
                <cc1:Editor 
                    ID="Editor1" 
                    Width="850px"  
                    Height="400px"
                    runat="server" 
                     style="z-index: 1; direction:rtl; left: 137px; top: 485px; position: absolute; height: 400px; width: 850px;"/>
```

see direction is right to left.. But when I type... it doesnt type normally like I type in English and the phenomena aforementioned happens..

Answer (score -1):

Set the direction tag in css to rtl. e.g :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="id1" runat="server" style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I did..set it..But it doesnt prevent it from doing so

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="id1" runat="server" style="direction:rtl; text-align:right" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: If you do not use javascript to render your texts in labels and etc, It would work correct. Can you share your design codes?

Comment: There is no design code.. I put text inside a label..as i described before..And in HTML Editor there is the same problem when you type...

Comment: Updated vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv